# Jmeter: How to override Content-Type in request to sent multipart/form-data

Tags: jmeter, multipart

In all my requests I need Content-Type=application/json, so I added HTTP Header manager under the Test Plan. 
But then inside of one of the threads, I need to upload image as a multipart request with additional parameters. I created HTTP request sampler, checked 'Use multipart/form-data', added file on File Uploads tab, added parametres on the Parameters tab. But Content-Type=application/json was sent in headers, so the request was failed.

I tried:

1. To add additional HTTP Header manager under the request with
   `Content-Type=multipart/form-data;
   boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary6dcBYcLBBPisdP1e.` But in the body of
   the sent request, Jmeter added another boundary (randomly generated)
   so the request was failed
2. To add `Content-Type=multipart/form-data` without boundary, but it didn't work (error that boundary is required)
3. To write body of multipart request myself, so my boundary is used. It worked for txt files, but I had problem with reading data from image file, so all images were broken when loaded (I used `${__FileToString(${pathToImage},,)}` to read file content and add it the request body).

**Is there any option to override content type as multipart/form-data and to add boundary that will be then used by Jmeter in body?** I can remove the header manager from the test plan, in that case multipart request will be sent with `Content-Type=multipart/form-data; boundary=----%randomly_generated_by_jmeter%`. But in that case I'll need to add application/json content type to all other requests (and there are lot of them).

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am facing the exact same issue

Comment: I decided ti use option 3: To write body of multipart request myself, so my boundary is used.